# How does the Disk Defragmenter in Windows 7 optomize the main OS boot volume?

Tags: windows-7, defragment

When checking under the "Application" section of my event logs from within the Event Viewer, I often see references that the Disk Defragment service has completed boot optimization on my main operating system volume - but I can't seem to find out exactly what this means or how the Disk Defragmenter goes about doing this. Would somebody be able to explain how this is done?

Comment: Windows normally reads a file, but if you change that file & make it larger, then the additional data is written to a new location on drive. Then system has to read two locations to fully read new file. Windows defrag then rewrites all files to be together so drive does not have to move to two locations. NTFS normally stores all files at beginning of partition. Linux does it differently. It uses entire drive and always writes the full file, and if needed to a new location on drive.

Comment: @oldfred That’s not entirely accurate. What you describe last is (roughly) a copy-on-write file system. Linux also has regular file systems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Disk Defragmenter has 3 modes of operation:

**File Defragmentation:**
Files that have more than one (or two perhaps) fragments will be moved to the first available extent that is large enough to hold it, thus making the file contiguous.  This mode is fast because there aren't usually very many files that are individually fragmented on an NTFS volume.  NTFS already prefers to allocate whole extents for new files.  The only time files become fragmented on an NTFS volume is when new blocks must be allocated for an existing file and there isn't enough free space next to it to do so.  In this scenario, NTFS will fragment the file on purpose to satisfy the I/O request faster.

**Free Space Consolidation:**
Even if there are no fragmented files on the volume, there may still be many small gaps between them.  A small number of large gaps is preferable to a large number of small gaps.  The latter makes it more likely that none of them will be large enough to allocate contiguous extents for future files or file growth.  This becomes a big problem when the volume is nearly full.  Free space consolidation rearranges the files so that both the allocated and free space on the disk are in large, contiguous regions.  This operation is very costly on a heavily fragmented volume because it has to touch nearly every single file.  Disk Defragmenter will never perform a free space consolidation unless you run it manually.

**Boot Optimization:**
Files critical to booting and running the operating system (like the registry, for example) are placed in the lowest-numbered blocks (i.e. at the "front") of the volume.  Physical hard drives spin with a constant linear velocity and record data from the outside edge of the platters inward.  That means that data near the beginning of the volume is physically faster to access than data near the end of it.  For modern hard drives, it can be as much as 100MB/sec faster.  Boot optimization is a very quick operation because the files needed for booting and running the OS rarely change.

---

I should note here that all of this is only relevant for spinning hard drives; none of this is applicable to SSDs.  Physical arrangement of files on an SSD does not matter.  Every cell has the same access time, multiple non-adjacent cells can be accessed simultaneously, and the controller can renumber virtual data blocks without physically moving any of the data (or can physically move the data without renumbering the blocks).

Since flash memory has write endurance limits, defragmenting an SSD can actually wear it out faster.  However, Windows (and its defragger) has been SSD-aware since XP.  Also SSDs are not as fragile as they used to be.  The bottom line here is that in the very best-case scenario, there is zero benefit to defragmenting an SSD.

Answer (score 0):

Look in Accessories, System Tools, Disk Defragmenter application. It has a schedule to run regularly which is why you see it in Event Viewer. You can watch it run and see it re-arrange file segments to be contiguous. This helps the hard drive to run more efficiently.

[image]

Comment: Thank you. In the context of this particular question, I was looking for a description of exactly what the Disk Defragmenter does when it says that boot optomizations have been made - this suggests that only changes were made to assist Windows in booting, rather than an entire defrag of the drive. Hopefully this makes sense!

Comment: Disk defragmenter does the whole drive and the boot sector does not usually need defragmenting (not in my experience). Once the files for booting are "near the front" they will not usually defrag again because they do not change a whole lot (again in my experience)

Comment: Also remember that some files (like the paging file) are not movable by defragging and so stay put. Boot files that can be moved consolidate near the front as I noted earlier